# async void method not returning immediately (EF6)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-6

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.Initialise(); // Does not return immediately. Why?
    }

    private async void Initialise();
    {
        await this.db.Entities.LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

If I change Initialise to use await Task.Run() to call the synchronous this.db.Entities.Load() then it returns immediately as expected.

Comment: On a side note, it's best to avoid `async void`. I have some [alternative approaches to `async` initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) on my blog.

Comment: This class is a viewmodel and thus contains other state information for the view such as whether buttons are enabled. I need to return the constructed object instantly or the view will be in an undefined state. The async method simply populates properties which are already bound when the viewmodel is constructed and the data appears on the screen asynchronously. Since it's a WPF app, exceptions will be caught on the UI thread's synchronization context (unlike a Windows Phone / Windows 8 Store app).

Comment: I understand that and reiterate my suggestion that you use the async initialization approach. The only difference from `async void` is that you properly handle errors (and can even handle exceptional situations via data binding). WP and Win8 apps have the same `async void` exception handling as WPF - it gets raised on the UI thread's `SyncContext`. But if you handle exceptions there you are applying a global solution to a local problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code will execute as far as the first awaitable point (for data that has not already completed). Keep in mind that the `Initialise` is effectively:

```
var tmp = this.db.Entities.LoadAsync();
await tmp;
```

So we must conclude that `LoadAsync` took a non-trivial amount of time before it yielded. Which is well within the API limits - the `await` API only helps make things awaitable; it doesn't guarantee that everything in non-blocking. For example, the following is perfectly awaitable:

```
static Task<int> Evil() {
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    return Task.FromResult(4);
}
```

It could be that the data-context is loading metadata, loading assemblies, etc - before it knows whether or not it can yield.

Comment: I believe the delay is due to Entity Framework warming up the first time a DbContext instance is used. The LoadAsync() method is probably only performing the database I/O asynchronously. The warm up takes far longer than any database query in my application. The only solution is to perform a "warm up query" within a full fledged Task.Run() and then use await for subsequent Async methods.